# Mouse not clicking during GUI automation with python

Tags: python, user-interface, error-handling, automation, bots

I am trying to build a desktop bot which auto promotes the art on society6.
For now i just want the mouse to scroll over then art image and once the heart shape is visible, then it should click on it.
[page on which I want my program to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxtVb.jpg)

[Image which i want to click on](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqhu7.jpg)

the program which I made

```
import pyautogui
i = 0
while i < 700:
 pyautogui.moveTo(400,i,2)
 i += 50
 promote = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('heart.JPG')
 x, y = pyautogui.center(promote)
 pyautogui.click(x,y)
```

But i am getting an error of not finding the image, i have saved image right next to program in the directory. How do i solve this problem?

this is the error 
     $ C:/Users/sultan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:
     /Users/sultan/python/society6-bot.py
     Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "c:/Users/sultan/python/society6-bot.py", line 7, in 
     x, y = pyautogui.center(promote)
     File "C:\Users\sultan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site- 
     packages\pyscreeze__init__.py", line 407, in center
     return (coords[0] + int(coords[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqhu7.jpg) / 2), coords[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uxtVb.jpg) + int(coords[3] / 2))
     TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Answer (score 0):

> replace `JPG` with lowercase `jpg`

`promote = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('heart.jpg')`

> File types are defined by lowercase and locateOnScreen is case sensetive and will therefore not work

Comment: tried but didn't work, this is the error - C:/Users/sultan/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:
/Users/sultan/python/society6-bot.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/sultan/python/society6-bot.py", line 7, in <module>
    x, y = pyautogui.center(promote)
  File "C:\Users\sultan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 407, in center
    return (coords[0] + int(coords[2] / 2), coords[1] + int(coords[3] / 2))
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable